# Bootcamp stuck at partitioning disk, lost half my disk space

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

recently I attempted to install windows on a macbook air 13’ mid 2014 256GB using boot camp. It was going well until it got stuck at the partitioning disk step, the blue loading bar was full and my mac was frozen. I restarted the mac using the power button but when I check the storage it says my SSD is only 175GB (I gave windows around 75GB of space in boot camp when trying to install btw) instead of 256GB which is the true size of the disk.

I have already erasing the disk using disk utility and then reinstalling mac os high sierra but that did not help.

Comment: Try entering the command `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` in a Terminal application window.

Comment: Note that a couple of the signs of an HD/SSD that is failing is that you "lose" disk space (bad blocks being mapped out) or disk-bound operations taking a lot longer than usual.So **back up your disk** just in case this is what is happening.